# How to make a bifurcation diagram of the Lorenz system under a varying parameter value?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to represent the behaviour of the system $\color{red}{r}$ varies from $\color{red}{1}$ to $\color{red}{100}$ **statically** (for instance something similar to a bifurcation graph)?

\begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt} &= \color{green}{10} \left(y-x\right) \\ \frac{dy}{dt}&= \color{red}{r}x -y - xz\\\ \frac{dz}{dt}&= xy -\color{green}{6}z \end{align}

How was this done?[image]

Comment: you have $\frac{dx}{dt}$ twice in there? Also what is $s$ and $b$? Do you have values for these?

Comment: my bad. fixed! @Nasser

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you want a picture like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udelG.jpg) from [here](http://complex.upf.es/~josep/Chaos.html)?

Comment: Dear @J.M. yes that is exactly what I want. What are they plotting on the vertical axis in that bifurcation graph?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you want a plot of the extrema of one of the variables (maybe `z[t]` vs `r`).  We can step through `r` values in a loop and save the extrema like this:

```
res = Internal`Bag[]; (* a place to store results *)

tmax = 100; (* how long to run for each r value *)
{x0, y0, z0} = {1, 1, 1}; (* initial ICs *)

Do[
  sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == 10 (y[t] - x[t]),
    y'[t] == r x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t],
    z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 6 z[t],
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0,
    (* save extrema of z[t] *)
    WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]
   }, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

  (* save end value for next ICs *)
  {x0, y0, z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;
, {r, 200, 40, -0.1}];

ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All],
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]},
  AxesLabel -> {"r", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A few notes:

1. This takes a few minutes to run to get a nice looking result.
2. Using final values from one run as initial conditions for the next is an easy way to stay near the attractor.
3. Your value of `b=6` is different than the `b=8/3` used in the link, which is why the diagram is a little different.
4. There may be alternative attractors for ranges of the parameter that this method will not find.  It will also not find unstable limit sets.

Comment: So the axes are going to be labeled r and z?

Comment: @Leif Yes, I have labeled them now.

Comment: How to do this without using Internal`Bag[]

Comment: @user84456 You could try `Sow`/`Reap`.

Comment: I tried your code by replacing the `InternalStuffBag` section with `Sow[{r, z[t]}]`.. but did not get the desired result

Answer (score 4):

How about this? I just did direct solve and plot. Nothing fancy. Not sure if this is what you want or not. This can be made more use-friendly if needed

[image]

```
Manipulate[

 eq1 = x'[t] == s (y[t] - x[t]);
 eq2 = y'[t] == r x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t];
 eq3 = z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - b z[t];

 sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, 
       {x, y, z}, {t, 0, maxT}];

 ParametricPlot3D[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t], sol[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, maxT}, 
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
       PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> {300, 300}],

 (*controls*)
 {{r, 15, "r"}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{s, 6, "s"}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{b, 10, "b"}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{maxT, 10, "time?"}, .1, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},

 Delimiter, (*initial conditions*)
 {{x0, 1, "x[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{y0, 0, "y[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{z0, 0, "z[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 ContinuousAction -> False

 ]
```