# Bifurcation diagram of nonlinear system of ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

Welcome to all, I try to apply most suggestion codes of a plot bifurcation diagram but I could not, I got an error. Is there anyone who can help me to understand how I can  plot a bifurcation diagram for the following system:

```
r = 0.431201; β1 = 2.99*10^-6; β2 = 1;
α1 = 0.44257; α2 = 0.4 ; α3 = 2.99*10^-6;
k1 = 0.11; k2 = 0.99; c1 = 0.33; c2 = 0.66;
sys3 = {
  N1'[t] == r N1[t] (1 - β1 N1[t]) - β2 N1[t] T[t] + c1 V[t] N1[t],
  T'[t] == α1 T[t] (1 - α2 T[t]) + α3 N1[t] T[t] - c2 V[t] T[t],
  V'[t] == k1 - k2 V[t]};
con3 = {N1[0] == 1, T[0] == 1, V[0] == 2};
s3 = NDSolve[{sys3, con3}, {N1, T, V}, {t, 0, 360}]
```

here, I want to plot the bifurction diagram of the system, 
also, the @zhk solve my problem for parametric solution code, but stil my qustion does not had a complete solution.

Comment: What do you want on the x and y axes of this bifurcation diagram?  Also, could you say what the model represents?

Comment: I want to see the effect of equation 3 on the behaviour of N1and T this model describes the behaviour of normal and tumor cells.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean by "equation 3".  Is there one particular parameter of interest?

Comment: can study more than one parameter,  actually, the behaviour of the model has affected by  \beta_2, c_1, c_2 , \alhpha _3 and k2  but I do not if I can examine all these parameters where already I know that the values of them

Comment: @sanaalharbi How about this? `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@{N1[t], T[t], V[t]} /. s3, {t, 0, 360}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}}]`

Comment: @zhk I used this code to plot the parametric solution in 3d, but I think the result need to improve too

Comment: @sanaalharbi You should double check your equations and parameters values.

Comment: okay noted thanks Dr. zhk @zhk

Comment: You say that your question doesn't have a complete solution -- what is missing in my answer?

Comment: This isn't a total duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159211/how-to-make-a-bifurcation-diagram-of-the-lorenz-system-under-a-varying-parameter), since this problem deals with stable equilibria which can be found with `FindRoot` and the linked one deals with non-equilibrium attractors.

Comment: the main question of how can I plot the bifurcation diagram? I found the equilibrium points and  analyzed them.

Comment: but I want to study the bifurcation case and plot it. maybe I do not have a good experience in this field. Maybe I am not good at this topic and need someone to help me about how to plot it by Mathematica  @Chris K

Comment: My answer plots the (presumably) stable equilibrium vs a parameter.  Is this not a bifurcation diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
r = 0.431201; \[Beta]1 = 2.99*10^-6;\[Alpha]1 = 0.44257; \[Alpha]2 = 0.4;

Manipulate[

eq1 = x'[t] == r x[t] (1 - \[Beta]1 x[t]) - \[Beta]2 x[t] y[t] + c1 z[t] x[t];
eq2 = y'[t] == \[Alpha]1 y[t] (1 - \[Alpha]2 y[t]) + \[Alpha]3 x[t] y[t] - c2 z[t] y[t];
eq3 = z'[t] == k1 - k2 z[t];

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 360}];

ParametricPlot3D[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t], sol[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, 360}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
PlotRange -> All,  ImageSize -> {300, 300}],
{{c2, 0.4975, "c2"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{c1, 0.2215, "c1"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
{{k1, 0.8677, "k1"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{k2, 0.9611, "k2"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{\[Beta]2, 0.9817, "\[Beta]2"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{\[Alpha]3 , 0.2291, "\[Alpha]3"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
Delimiter,
{{x0, 1,"x[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{y0, 1, "y[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
{{z0, 0, "z[0]"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
                 ControlPlacement -> Left, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** Experiment with different values for the parameters and the initial conditions.

Comment: THANKS. THAT IS GOOD FOR FIND A PARAMETRIC PLOT3D. WHAT ABOUT THE BIFRECTION AS SHOWN BY LINK@ZHK

Comment: @sanaalharbi You already got an answer for that by ChrisK

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time for a full analysis of your problem, but here are some thoughts and a rough approach to a bifurcation diagram.

First, the $V$ equation is decoupled from the others, so you should be able to solve for its equilibrium value $\hat V=k_1/k_2$ and inject it into the other two equations.  Then regrouping of terms would reduce the number of independent parameters and also allow phase-plane analysis.

Once you've done that, I think you'll find the normal ($N_1$) and tumor cells ($T$) follow a combination of the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model with logistic growth of both prey and predators.  I think you could show that if a positive equilibrium exists it is unique and asymptotically stable.

This justifies a rough approach to generating a bifurcation diagram, using `FindRoot` to find an equilibrium for a given parameter value, then looping over the parameter value using the  previous answer as an initial guess.

```
N1res = Tres = Vres = {}; (* results to be accumulated here *)
{N1i, Ti, Vi} = {21000, 0.6, k1/k2}; (* first initial guess *)
Do[
  eq = FindRoot[sys3 /. {_'[t] -> 0, var_[t] -> var},
    (* remove [t] and set time derivatives equal to zero *)
    {N1, N1i}, {T, Ti}, {V, Vi}];
  (* store results *)
  AppendTo[N1res, {k1, N1 /. eq}];
  AppendTo[Tres, {k1, T /. eq}];
  AppendTo[Vres, {k1, V /. eq}];
  (* update initial guess *)
  {N1i, Ti, Vi} = {N1, T, V} /. eq
, {k1, 0.6, 10.0, 0.1}]
```

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ListPlot[N1res, AxesLabel -> {"k1", "N1"}],
  ListPlot[Tres, AxesLabel -> {"k1", "T"}],
  ListPlot[Vres, AxesLabel -> {"k1", "V"}]
  }, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This could be improved in many ways, but hopefully it gets you started.

Comment: I analyzed the stability of the model it was stable when the cells succeed to live together.  but there is no growth for the third equation.@chris k

Comment: The equation for $V$ is independent of the other variables $N_1$ and $T$, so in all cases $V\to k_1/k_2$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: yes, that means,  V is bounded, I proved that anlytically