# Bifurcation diagram for Lorenz attractor

Tags: export, output-formatting, event-detection, sow-reap, table

As I was following a similar question I came across a beautiful answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159238/84456). However, in that code, he used `InternalBag[]` which heavily depends on ram that I can't afford and I need to make a data file too. So Please Help me edit this code so that I can export the data to my hard disk.

Along with that, this code only stores the **extremum** values of Z as in `WhenEvent` there is only one condition i.e. `z'[t]==0`. I want to store **minimum** and **maximum** values in two different columns. How do I do that?

```
res = Internal`Bag[];(*a place to store results*)
tmax = 100;(*how long to run for each r value*)
{x0, y0, z0} = {10, 10, 10};(*initial ICs*)

Do[sol = With[{a = 10.0, c = 8/3},
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == a (y[t] - x[t]), 
      y'[t] == r x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - c*z[t],
       x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
      WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]}, {x, 
  y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[1]];
 (*save end value for next ICs*){x0, y0, z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 100, 10, -0.1}];

ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "z"}]
```

> I was suggested to use `Reap` or `Sow`, but I am unable to edit the
> code properly

Comment: Glad you got an answer to your question. BTW, where did you see that ``Internal`Bag`` is obsolete?

Comment: @ChrisK Sorry, I was wrong there. It's not obsolete but it heavily depends on ram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example how you would use Sow and Reap. Note, I decreased the r interval, as I did not want to wait a long time.

```
tmax = 100;(*how long to run for each r value*)
{x0, y0, z0} = {10, 10, 10};(*initial ICs*)

res = Reap[
    Do[sol = 
      With[{a = 10.0, c = 8/3}, 
        NDSolve[{x'[t] == a (y[t] - x[t]), 
          y'[t] == r x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
          z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - c*z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
          z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
          WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Sow[{r, z[t]}]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
          tmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
         MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[1]];
     (*save end value for next ICs*){x0, y0, 
       z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 11, 
      10, -0.1}]][[2]];

ListPlot[res, PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "z"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I separate minimum and maximum values in `WhenEvent`?

Comment: In the WhenEvent you only have access to 3 data: t, z[t] and z'[t]. That is not enough to determine if we have a min or max. But "sol" contains the whole function and you may use it to determine if it is min or max.